Family photo where the father was looking at his daughter, who was standing beside a desk with a razor
I watched a movie a while ago but can't remember much about it or what it was called, and I am dying to find out. 
In the movie there was a family photo where the father was looking down at his daughter, who was standing beside a desk with a razor blade on it. If I remember correctly the father was trying to warn people about his killer daughter who I think killed people by turning things people ate into razor blades, or something like that. 
The razor blade was one of those shaving razors that barbers use. The father is tall and skinny and the daughter is maybe around 10 years old. On the photo the father is looking down to his right, which is down at his maybe 10 year old daughter. I may be wrong because as i said its been a while since i saw this movie, but I'm pretty sure the father wore a black suit and his daughter some kind of a dress. To be honest not even sure if this is a horror movie.
My friend is convinced that I'm making this up. Am I?  What movie am I thinking of? Please help!

If all you have is that one image, you're going to need to be a lot more specific. When did you see this? Can you describe the father and daughter (what did they look like, how old are they, what were they wearing, etc)? What sort of razor blade? A straight razor? Consider posting an image of what type of razor it was (or at least a similar one).

That sounds a lot like an episode from the Supernatural tv show (season 1, episode 19). The only major difference is that she wasn't turning things people ate into razor blades, but she was coming out of the painting and killing the people with the razor from the painting
Here's the painting representing the family. 
http://www.supernatural.tv/reviews/legends/prov.jpg

Yes, thats it! tank you so much @incominggame. I knew i had seen it somewhere.

I'm glad I could help. If you are satisfied with the answer, don't forget to accept it.
